# Probability calculation in tennis match situation

Tags: probability

First of all sorry for the mistakes but English isn’t my mother tongue.

I want to find out if what I want to achieve is even possible.
The theme is a tennis match.

I know its possible to predict the outcome when compairing two players.

Stats Player A:
Service points won: 78.4%
Return points won: 24.7%

Stats Player B:
Service points won: 69.6%
Return points won: 21.1%

Now, I’ve collected stats about each player on how they historically performed in a specific match situation. 
The situation is 4-2 (and above, 5-3, 5-4) in other words there is 1 break of serve.
The stats give me and idea on how the player performs when leading or behind when they are at the business end of set/match.

Player A:
Wins the set/match when leading in the above situation: 54%
Loses the set/match when leading: 21%

Player B:
Wins: 67%
Loses: 9%

The some of win and lose are not 100% because wins are not related to loses. The situation is complete different. Its not every match that the above scores happen.

Now I want to find out if I can dona probability calculations when these two players play against each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of two problems, one of pure math, and one of mathematical modeling.

The purely mathematical problem is: given the chance that A will win a point when A serves, and the chance that A will win a point when B serves, what is the probability that A will win the set, given that A currently leads 4-2 (and presumably assuming that A is serving the next set). You solve this in two stages:

First calculate the chance that each player will win a game when A is serving, given that the chance that A will win a point is p. We break this down into the sum of two components: The probability that A will win within the first 4 points, and the probability that A will win if the score is 30-30 (deuce) after the first 4 points, multiplied by the chance that deuce will be reached after 4 points.

The chance that A will win in the first 4 points is p^4 + 4 p^3(1 - p).
The chance that the score will be tied after 4 points is 6 p^2(1-p)^2.

Let the chance that A will win once the score is tied be q. Then A can win either by winning the next two points (probability p^2), or by winning 1 of the next 2 ponts (probability 2p(1-p)) and then winning after the resulting tie (probability q). So this tells us that

q = p^2 + 2p(1-p)q

So q = p^2 / (1 - (2p(1-p)),

and the overall chance that A will win the game is then given by p^4 + 4p^3(1-p)q.

A similar calculation can be used, once we know the probability that each player will win a game, to determine the chance that each will win the set. You'd need to specify whether a tiebreak is played at 6-6, or whether the set continues until one side has won by 2 games to make this calculation.

But before any of this happens, we need to solve the mathematical modeling question. We have a probability that A wins a point when serving (presumably derived from A serving to a variety of opponents, not just B), and the probability of B winning a point when returning (again, against a variety of opponents, not just A). Call those probabilities x and y. Since x and y do not sum to 1, we cannot use them as estimates of A or B winning the point when A serves to B. This is a problem of mathematical modeling, not mathematics. The simplest thing to do would be just to normalize, using a probability that A will win serving against B of x/(x+y), and a probability that B will win of y/(x+y). But you'd need to do some comparisons against real-world results to see if this is a good model. And if you have more data, you can make a better model. For example, if you have more data on A than on B, you might give a higher weight to x than to y estimating p.

Comment: Whaw Andy, this is an excellent answer. How donI translate all this in an example with the stats that I have give ?